# backgrounds in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a listview with a bunch of items in it, each item has its own background, the problem is that if i only have one item in a list, the rest of the "empty" slots of the list is black. I tried applying a background around the listview and also on the view that sorrounds it (relativeView) and i get a strange margin around the whole list like the picture at the bottom. The question i have is, how can i remove the actual "borders" around the list so it still fills upp its parent ? .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove any padding you may have used in your XML layout file.

Comment: I still got the border around it, don't think its the padding in the actual list that does that, i got no padding in the main view that contains the list and the header either.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in the following code in the listview's layout:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:fadingEdge="none"` in listview in layout

Answer (score 0):

Change your listview height like this `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`